# Printing user settings (with certain criteria)

Tags: ibm-midrange

On a IBM AS400-system, when searching for a user with `WRKUSRPRF <user>` and then selecting a certain entry with `5` I can see some details (STATUS, Last login, ...).

Now my question: is there a way to select some user (e.g. based on last login date) and print the usernamen and a certain value of this entity (e.g. last login date)? So the output is either displayed or saved as spoolfile.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there are simpler ways. Normally i dump output from DSPUSRPRF, then query the file using sql (wrkqry or other tools).

e.g.
`DSPUSRPRF USRPRF(*ALL) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(MYLIB/ALLUSER)`

then

```
    SELECT A.UPUPRF AS USER_ID
      , CASE WHEN A.UPPSOC ='1' THEN '20' || UPPSOD
          ELSE '19' || UPPSOD END   AS LAST_LOGIN  
      ,A.UPSTAT AS STATUS
      ,A.UPJBDS AS JOBD
      ,A.UPTEXT  
    FROM MYLIB.ALLUSER  A 
    WHERE A.UPPSOC = '1' AND ('20' || UPPSOD) >= '20161001'
    ORDER BY A.UPJBDS,A.UPUPRF
```

Comment: perfect! exactly what I searched for! Thanks :D